# Power Emitted by a black body calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation

While I was doing a practice physics exam I came across this question

"The absolute temperature of a black body increases by 2 %. What is the percentage increase in the power emitted by the black body?"

A. 2
B. 4
C. 8
D. 16

The way I approached it was as follows:

Since $P = σAT^4$

If the temperature increases by 2 %, the percentage increase in the power emitted should be $((1.02)^4 - 1) * 100$ . Which gives me the correct answer C (8%). The problem however is that this is a no calculator exam, so technically I would need to calculate this by hand which would be very time consuming. Is there any way to solve this without needing a calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binomial expansion of $(1+0.02)^4=1+4\cdot0.02+O(0.02^2)$, so with that approximation you'd get 8% without a calculator.

Comment: Ohh ok thank you

Comment: This is obviously a simple homework question that you have done for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it more generally.

Say $y$ is related to $x$ by a power $n$, through the formula
$$
y = A x^n
$$
where $A$ is a constant. Now suppose $x$ increases to $x_1$ given by
$$
x_1 = (1 + r) x
$$
where $r$ is small. (For example a $2\%$ increase corresponds to $r=0.02$.) Let's see what happens to $y$:
$$
y_1 = A x_1^n = A ((1+r) x)^n = (1+r)^n A x^n
$$
so the fractional change in $y$ is
$$
\frac{y_1}{y} = (1+r)^n.
$$
Now if $r$ is less than one than we can use the binomial expansion:
$$
(1+r)^n = 1 + n r + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} r^2 + \cdots + \; _n\! C_k  \; r^k + \cdots
$$
For small $r$, this can be approximated as $1 + nr$ and the error in the approximation is about $(n r)^2/2$. For $r=0.02$ and $n=4$ this error is $0.08^2/2 \simeq 0.003$.